# Как показывать на мобильниках минимальную ширину страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Чистая верстка test.buyhtml.ru минимальная ширина 768, но когда захожу с мобильника

[image: картинка]

то экран фокусируется на реальном разрешении мобильника, когда тыкну по экрану два раза то становится так как надо, вот в чем загвоздка, хочу что бы без этих двух тыков было сразу минимальная ширина 768 пикселов.

[image: картинка2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел, благодаря эксперементам с viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Надо было убрать initial-scale=1.0

Comment: расскажите пожалуйста о параметре "shrink-to-fit=no". Я о нем ничего толкового не нахожу. Столкнувшись с похожей проблемой я просто прописала в вьюпорте только content="width=device-width

Comment: Можно прочесть тут http://kihlstrom.com/2015/shrink-to-fit-no-fixes-zoom-problem-in-ios-9/

Если кратко:

В iOS 9 Apple изменила способ управления масштабированием экрана. Раньше, если вы добавили viewport "widh=device-width, initial-scale=1" в head, вы знали, что страница будет отображаться на ширине устройства.
После выхода iOS 9 это уже не так. Теперь браузер автоматически уменьшает масштаб, чтобы учесть все. Это можно исправить добавив shrink-to-fit = no

Comment: спасибо большое за ссылку!